# HP-UFT WPF TextBlock object capture

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, automated-tests, hp-uft

I am working on a WPF application where we have to automate testing. 
This work fine for many components but we struggle to check a summary page where we use TextBlock to display our data.

The WPF TextBlock is not found by the HP tool. Thus we cannot check the values that we display.

We tried the following solutions but without success:

- Change x:Name in Name (not the best idea right, but we tried all!)
- AutomationProperties.AutomationId on the TextBloc
- AutomationProperties.Name
- Make the TextBlock focusable
- The solution presented here: [WPF Tutorial Solution](http://www.wpftutorial.net/UIAutomation.html)

None of them Worked and we are currently blocked.

Has anyone experience with this? Is there a clean solution to solve this issue?

What we need: access TextBlock content, in particular Text from HP UFT Tool.

Comment: Not familiar specifically, did you try `AutomationProperties.LabeledBy` also? (Shot in the dark)

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for your input. We tried it right away but sadly without success...

Answer (score 0):

Here the correct answer:-

1) Open UFT
2) Open your wfp ".exe" file in UFT and run. (YourwpfFile.exe)
3) then you can able to identify the WFP window using object spy.